# what is the correct way of using relative paths in wordpress theme development?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am writing a some code for wordpress theme development that I plan on reusing for future themes (maybe even uploading to github).
it consist of a few dozen files and some javascript and css files as well.

the only commitment I am willing to make for the future is that all my files will be placed in the same directory, where will this directory be placed inside the theme directory is unknown.

how should I go about enqueuing files (wp_enqueue_style, wp_enqueue_script functions) if I don't know the files absolute path (get_template_directory_uri . '')?

also I hope that instead of having a dozen lines of include\require, I can write one include file that will include the rest of the files by their relative paths.

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution, (not necessarily the most proper way) if you're needing the path within the theme index file could be something like so:

```
 <?php
        $TEMPLATE_PATH = get_template_directory_uri(); 
        $TEMPLATE_PATH = parse_url($TEMPLATE_PATH, PHP_URL_PATH);
      ?>
```

You'd then be able to use the $TEMPLATE_PATH as a relative path like so:

```
<link href="<?php echo $TEMPLATE_PATH; ?>/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

this would be output like the following:

```
<link href="/wp-content/themes/ThemesName/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `dirname(__FILE__)` to determine loader.php location,
and substracting `get_template_directory()` out of it to get the relative path of my code inside the theme directory like this:
`$MY_PATH =  str_replace(realpath(get_template_directory()),"",dirname(__FILE__)));`

end result load.php:

```
$MY_PATH =  str_replace(realpath(get_template_directory()),"",dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once('file1.php');
require_once('file2.php');
require_once('file3.php');

function my_scripts() {
    $mypath = $GLOBALS['MY_PATH'];
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', $template_directory_uri . $mypath . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', $template_directory_uri . $mypath . '/script.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

now I can change my code directory location without editing the code in loader.php.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main WP functions to use to find the relative paths within a theme:

[get_template_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)

[get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

You could create a theme subdirectory called 'reusable' or something appropriate, which is a top level subdirectory.  Furthermore, let's say your set of files are as follows:

```
mytheme/reusable/loader.php
mytheme/reusable/include-me.php
mytheme/reusable/include-another.php
mytheme/reusable/js/reuse.js
mytheme/reusable/css/reuse.css
```

loader.php:

```
<?php
// add as many files as you want to this array
$include_paths = array(
    'reusable/include-me.php',
    'reusable/include-another.php',
);
// loop through the paths and include them if they exist
$template_directory = trailingslashit(get_template_directory());
foreach( $include_paths as $path ) {
    $complete_path = $template_directory . $path;
    if( file_exists( $complete_path ) ) {
        include($complete_path);
    }
}
// function to enqueue js and css
function reusable_enqueue_scripts() {
    $template_directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'reusable-style', $template_directory_uri . '/css/reuse.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reusable-js', $template_directory_uri . '/js/reuse.js');
}
// add function to enqueue action hook
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'reusable_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Then in your theme's functions.php file:

```
$reusable = trailingslashit(get_template_directory()).'reusable/loader.php';
include($reusable);
```

There's also a very useful WP function called `get_template_part()` that you can [look into](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/), might change how you're thinking about a solution.

Comment: your answer assumes that my files are always in 'mytheme/reusable', directory, but it can also be 'mytheme/inc' or something else. I want it dynamic.
I tested successfully having all my files in one directory along with a loader.php file similar to this:
`include ('file1.php'); //relative to loader.php
include ('file2.php');`
then in the function.php: `include (get_template_directory() . 'dynamic-path/loader.php');` so I don't rely on constant paths.
As I said it worked with php files but I work out the enqueue part of it. also I don't know if it will work in the future or cause problems

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve theme directory URI from below WP function , you can then pass files name with respective folder name.

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```